# How to add Suffix text in JQuery Spinner

Tags: jquery, plugins

Is it possible to add suffix into jQuery spinner (jquery.ui.spinner). e.g: 10.02%.

I tried following, from [`jquery.ui.spinner`](https://github.com/newicon/jquery.ui.spinner) [under Option section], but it did not work for me.

```
$("#spinner").spinner({
    step: 0.01,
    numberformat: "n",
    suffix: "%",
});
```

Appreciate the help in advance.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry. It should be Is it possible to add Suffix into JQuery spinner (jquery.ui.spinner). e.g: 10.02%.

Answer (score 13):

Have had the same problem.

With jQuery UI's widget factory it is quite easy:

```
$.widget( "ui.pcntspinner", $.ui.spinner, {
    _format: function(value) { return value + '%'; },

    _parse: function(value) { return parseFloat(value); }
});

$("#spinner").pcntspinner({ 
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    step: .01 });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aAHuT/

If integers are to be used '_parse' has to be adapted to use `parseInt()`:

```
_parse: function(value) { return parseInt(value); }
```

The jQuery UI example for the [Time Spinner](http://jqueryui.com/spinner/#time) has been very helpful for coming up with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible, since according to the docs on the page you linked to:

> suffix (string)
>
> Character suffix after the number.  Commonly used for percentage signs.  Defaults to ''.

If it did not work, what happened instead?

Comment: I'm not able to see the suffix symbol inside the spin widget, when I run the html page.  - Thank You!

Comment: Hmm. Is there any reason you are using a fork instead of the main branch of this project: https://github.com/btburnett3/jquery.ui.spinner ? I would suggest you try the main branch and see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yaQSP/) seems to work for me.

Comment: Could you please post, how you've achieved it Or please guide me where exactly I'm wrong. Thank You!

Comment: The hyperlink is already in my answer as the word `Demo` http://jsfiddle.net/yaQSP/

Comment: thanks a lot! But I'm using "jquery.ui.spinner" which comes with JQuery UI (It's in "jquery-ui-1.9m3\demos\spinner\decimal.html" folder) not the js provided by Brant Burnett (https://github.com/btburnett3/jquery.ui.spinner/blob/master/ui.spinner.min.js). Could you please suggest how to fix it with the JQuery provided lib. I appreciate your help. Thank You!

Comment: The official jQuery UI spinner is still in [active development](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137947/FrontPage) and currently does not support any form of `suffix` option. Worse still the step of `0.01` also causes rounding errors. I really would stick with the other spinner until jQuery 1.9 is final. Better still, ask this question in the [jQuery UI forum](http://forum.jquery.com/developing-jquery-ui), requesting these features or fork the code and implement them yourself for the jQuery UI team :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider adding an additional input showing a text with suffix, while the spinner is containing only number. That is a convenient way to work with posted data.

```
$( ".spinner" ).spinner({ 
    min: 1,
    max: 999,
    spin: function() {
        $(this).siblings('.spinner-text').val($(this).val()+' items');
    },
    stop: function() {
        $(this).siblings('.spinner-text').val($(this).val()+' items');
    }
 }).parent().append('<input class="spinner-text">');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6t9bS/3/

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best solution is to use CSS:

```
.percentspinner .ui-spinner:before {
    content: "%";
    width: 40px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

With following HTML:

```
<div class="percentspinner"><input id="spinner" type="text" value="10.02" /></div>
```

And JavaScript:

```
 $("#spinner").spinner({step: 0.01});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xTHCs/1/)

This is the simplest implementation to explain the idea, I'd suggest to use text-align and padding-right achieve desired flexibility.

I tried/considered many approaches but after that I came with this idea. From my point of view it has the most important benefits like: character "%" doesn't influence submitted content, user still can edit value but he don't need to think "what if I delete the character?", easy implementation...