# How can I append spec. character to JQuery-UI Spinner field

Tags: jquery-ui-spinner

Could anyone help me on how I can append an '%' character to the spinner text field value, please?

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, but it desn't work. This URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748645/how-to-add-suffix-text-in-jquery-spinner helped for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could help you:

```
$.widget( "ui.mySpinner", $.ui.spinner, {
    _format: function( value ) { return value + ' %'; },

    _parse: function(value) { return parseInt(value); //or parse to your datatype }
});

$("#spinnerId").mySpinner(
            min: 0,
        step: 100,
        stop: function() {
            $(this).siblings().val($(this).val());
        });
```

And in your html:

```
<input type="text" id="spinnerId" value="1">
```

EDIT

I found a eassier way to fix this problem, please find the solution here
http://jsfiddle.net/8P6Gf/

Comment: Thank you, but it desn't work. This URL stackoverflow.com/questions/6748645/… helped for me.