# Spinner as pixel selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, spinner

I created a jQuery spinner with

```
<input id="spinner" />
```

And

```
$("#spinner").spinner();
```

Now it showing like ,

[image]

But i want to create a spinner with a 'px' notation inside it,like the image below

[image]

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FNys7/32/)

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/spinner/#currency

Comment: @martynas I already checked this,But it is not working with currency only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the excellent [information found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17708266/3130094), you could do something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<input id="spinner" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$.widget("ui.pxspinner", $.ui.spinner, {
    _format: function (value) {
        return value + 'px';
    },
    _parse: function (value) {
        return parseInt(value);
    }
});

$("#spinner").pxspinner();
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/FNys7/35/).